# Object already in use elsewhere

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

[image]*When I am drag picture Box in Windows form it's showing as Object already in use elsewhere.*

I searched over Stack overflow and other website says that error is Threads, Coding oriented and GDI+. But I didn't write any coding in that. I just drag the picture box. Then it shows “already in use elsewhere”.

Anyone Explain?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of error in your question

Comment: 10 Reputation is needed to add screenshot. So only i couldn't add screenshot.

Comment: This shouldn't happen of course.  Restart your PC and create a new, clean Project. When the problem persists, reinstall/repair VS.

Comment: Henk@ I Restarted PC, Reinstalled the VS and OS too

Comment: And started a new Project?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes. But same error

Comment: Well, I'm out of guesses. When are still hoping for an answer here, document this more thoroughly. What Windows version, dotNet version,  is the project in a special folder, etc.

Comment: Also, try to create and use a Picture Box in code, and examine any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an indicator that something else, potentially some other thread in your own application, already has the target file that you're trying to save locked at the file system level. If you look at the inner exception I believe it should mention this. If it's not directly in the InnerException Another way to confirm this (or discover what it might really be instead) is to turn on first chance exceptions in the debugger and watch for what exception is being thrown "underneath" Save and then being turned into this generic exception.
A Generic Error occured at GDI+ in asp.net mostly because of missing target folder / access permissions.

Comment: Looking at the error would require debugging VS itself. Not all that easy.

Comment: @HenkHolterman After the edits a picture upload looks like you are right it aint related to his coding issue but VS.

Comment: @Jerin I debugged it as you said, And its the result 
"System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write Protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt at system.Drawing.SafeNativeMethod.Gdip.GdipDrawRectangel
(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef pen, Int32 x, 32y height)"

Comment: Well that error used to popup when I used to add a bitmap image as source to the picture box but since you havent done any coding on your end then it must be Visual Studio error.

Comment: Since there isnt any code behind and you just dragged and dropped a picture box in a new project the error shouldnt have poped up unless your VS installation had some corrupt file or the some registry bug might have crept in. All that I could think of reinstall and update your VS.